# RxJava unit testing in Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm trying to unit test my code that uses RxJava's `Observable#flatMap`, but I'm running into `java.lang.NullPointerException`. How do I write my unit test (and avoid the exception)?

*Code to be unit tested:*

```java
public void submit(final NameRequest request, final AgeRequest ageRequest) {
    model.getAccountName(request)
        .flatMap(new Function<NameResponse, Observable<AgeResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<AgeResponse> apply(NameResponse response)
                    throws Exception {
                final Status status = response.getStatus();
                if (status.getCode() != 1) {
                    throw new Exception(status.getDescription());
                }
                return model.getAge(ageRequest);
            }
        }, new BiFunction<NameResponse, AgeResponse, AgeResponse>() {
            @Override
            public AgeResponse apply(NameResponse nameResponse, AgeResponse ageResponse) {
                ageResponse.setCustomerName(nameResponse.getName());
                return ageResponse;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

*Test code:*

```
val mockResponse = AgeResponse()
Mockito.doReturn(Observable.just(mockResponse))
                .`when`(mNetworkModel)
                .preSubmit(ageRequest)
mPresenter.submit(nameRequest, ageRequest)
```

Comment: that's not `kotlin` code. Did you mean `android` perhaps? The tags are misleading.

Comment: Where exactly does the `NullPointerException` occur? (What variable is `null`?)